# xlsxwriter sheet protection feature with limited privilege

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Does `xlsxwriter` provide the feature to protect a sheet enabling the add and delete column options to users ?

We use `python 2.7` .

Attaching an image of the excel to be more clear on the feature we are looking for .

I could not find any parallel apis for `xlsxwriter`

[image: excel sheet protection with limited privilege to user to add and delete column]

Answer (score 0):

> Does xlsxwriter provide the feature to protect a sheet enabling the add and delete column options to users

Yes, the [`worksheet.protect()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect) method allows you to protect some or all of the worksheet elements:

```
worksheet.protect('password', {'insert_columns': True, 
                               'delete_columns': True})
```